# How do put the border line under image?

Tags: html, css, less

I can't find solution for my problem so I posted this topic. Hope anyone can help me out.

[image]

As attached above image. In the "Service provided", the image overlay border line. I tried but can't do like this. Here my code:

http://codepen.io/thehung1724/pen/iykFu

Hope anyone can help me out. Thank in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're looking for?

Comment: i don't see the issue

Comment: You need to create the diamond image with the grey background instead of transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if i got your point, but if i am right, I recommend using two lines.

```
&:before,&:after{
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    width: 30%;
}
&:before{
    left: 50%;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
&:after{
  right: 50%;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bovgm

Answer (score 0):

You should instead place the png that is sitting currently under the line in CSS, like so:

```
.medium-seperator {
  background:url('transparent.png') repeat-x #c00;
  height:25px;
  display:block;
}
```

And instead put the line after so that the image appears on top:

```
&:after{
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    width: 80%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

This way you get the gap in the line you are looking for. Or instead just create one image for the border and the small icon. Not sure why you need to generate a border there. Make the entire thing a png.